# Adding numbers in textfile in one line

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am trying to add numbers in a file (one per line) to print out the 10 most frequently occurring numbers in descending frequency. I was asked to do this in 1 line, but I am not sure how to write a shell script for that.

To be a bit more clear, I am trying to to print out the 10 most frequently occurring numbers in descending frequency, from a textfile that has one number per line. I am not sure how to write a shell script for that in just one line?

I did some research and came across pipelines, i.e. using `|` operand in shell. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please show us what you already tried, then we can point you in the most promising direction or advise you of a better way. That way you can avoid contributors suggesting solutions you already know don't work.

Comment: A sample dataset, your current results, and your intended results [added to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/604309/edit) would be most helpful too, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. sort the file numerically
2. find the number of occurrences of each number (hint `uniq`)
3. sort *that* output by occurrences, numerically, descending
4. select the first 10 lines
5. remove the counts so you're left with just the original numbers.

All those things can be chained together in a pipeline.

Comment: This helped a lot thank you ! the uniq command was what I was missing